Failure when running WSL from TeamCity build
I tried to run the simplest WSL command from TeamCity build, but it failed.
The command:
wsl echo "Hello from WSL"

I get the following error:

The file cannot be accessed by the system

It works fine when running it from a command line on the agent itself.
